# Select N-th level child using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Below is my XML structure

```
<root>
<a>first level
    <b>second level
        <c>Third level
            <a>fourth level</a>
        </c>

    </b>
    <b>second level</b>
</a>
<a>first level</a>
</root>
```

I need to select only first and level of elements in hierarchy. Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please provide a better example? What do you mean by 'first and level of elements'?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest

```
<root>
<a>first level - first element
    <b>second level - first element
        <c>Third level
            <a>fourth level</a>
        </c>

    </b>
    <b>second level - second element</b>
</a>
<a>first level - second element</a>
</root>
```

You can iterate easily with the [index] through your structure.
Here are two examples for you:

- XPath example:

  ```
  /root/a[1]
  ```

  gives you

  ```
  first level - first element
      second level - first element
          Third level
              fourth level
  ```

---

- XPath example 2:

  ```
  /root/a[1]/b[2]
  ```

  gives you

  ```
  second level - second element
  ```

More examples on [microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms256086%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) or [test your expression online](http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/)